# Disabling Chrome cache for website development

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

I am modifying a site's appearance (CSS modifications) but can't see the result on Chrome because of annoying persistent cache. I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+refresh but it doesn't work.

How can I disable the cache temporarily or refresh the page in some way that I could see the changes?

Comment: This is probably the single worst Chrome bug.  I've wasted far too much time wondering why things were coming out wrong, only to find that--despite having forced a complete reload with ^F5--it's using an hour-old stale resource.

Comment: Browsers are supposed to cache. Remember, your users will also be caching - and so may not see changes that you make after your site is in production. The way to avoid this is to version your files. my_css.css?version=something_unique. If the browser hasn't seen the version before then it downloads the file again. something_unique could, for example, be last modifed date.

Comment: @user984003 `Ctrl+Shift+R` or `Shift+R` should flush the cache...

Comment: @user984003 Hi, can you elaborate a bit how to achieve that? Is it js or PHP? :) I'm very new in web development.

Comment: @user984003 Not if I tell them to not cache. Yes, a cache-busting version number is great for final release as that's what users are using, but when I'm building a new site and I want to see incremental changes as I go, I'm not changing the version number each time. Hence why I develop with Firefox - it has the most reliable cache-disabling options!

Comment: If I'm doing some heavy web testing/changes I usually just launch from the terminal (ubuntu):  google-chrome --incognito
You can throw other useful flags in there like --kiosk for fullscreen testing if that's a requirement.

Comment: @user984003 yes, browsers are supposed to cache... when browsing. When developing, you need more control over that.

Comment: Browsers are not supposed to cache when you reload the page.  That's why you reload the page.  No other browser ignores that user request.

Comment: It's really annoying. I always have the History tab opened and have to delete the cache after changing a .css or .js file. And get this - images keep getting cached even after that!! I have to use a file manager, go to the Cache and Media Cache and delete it manually to get a true reload of the images!

Comment: @GlennMaynard after a decade you reported, Its still there..... the same cacge issue

Answer (score 2099, accepted):

The Chrome DevTools can disable the cache.

1. **Right-click** and choose `Inspect Element` to open the DevTools. Or use one of the following [keyboard shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts):

- <kbd>F12</kbd>
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

1. **Click** `Network` in the toolbar to open the network pane.
2. **Check** the `Disable cache` checkbox at the top.

[image: screenshot of development tools panel]

Keep in mind, as a [tweet](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/227356682890670080) from [@ChromiumDev](https://twitter.com/chromiumdev) stated, this setting is **only active while the devtools are open**.

Note that this will result in *all* resources being reloaded. Should you desire to disable the cache only for some resources, you can [modify the HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/how-to-prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp) that your server sends alongside your files.

If you do not want to use the `Disable cache` checkbox, a long press on the refresh button **with the DevTools open** will show a menu with the options to `Hard Reload` or `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` which should have a similar effect. Read about the [difference between the options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a#14969509) to know which option to choose. The following shortcuts are available:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Mac
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Windows or Linux

[image: long press]

Comment: Shortcut for hard refresh on mac is Command + Shift + R

Comment: I find when testing a change in Amazon Cloudfront distribution setting, even "Disable Cache" in DevTools, or use "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" will not work. One must close the Incognito window, clear the cache manually, and then reopen the Incognito window, and reinput the URL to see the update, which is very inconvenient.

Comment: Doesn't work (Chrome 103, Mac). I am developing several apps in parallel, and I continually need to delete the cache manually. I'm not sure what this checkbox does, but it simply doesn't work. Another thing is that command+option+r does definitely not flush the cache. Yes, it reloads the page without using the cache, but when you load the page again without the option key you'll get the old stuff back. I have had to start using two different browsers. For everything where I want caching I use Safari, so I can manually flush the Chrome cache without hurting anything.

Comment: this only works when the devtools are open which totally kills the purpose if you are trying to eliminate caching for web dev purposes.  I have my server with VS code doing auto refresh and auto save but the caching in the browser is terrible.  I can't click refresh every time I make an edit.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: good, but does not work for json content type, hack for that is in url: `.../some.json?2`

Answer (score 259):

[image]

Clearing the cache is too annoying when you need to clear the cache 30 times an hour.. so I installed a Chrome Extension called **Classic Cache Killer** that clears the cache on every page load.

[Chrome Store Link (free)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic-cache-killer/kkmknnnjliniefekpicbaaobdnjjikfp/related)
*(Now without malware!)*

Now my mock json, javascript, css, html and data refreshes **every time** on **every page load**.

I *never* have to worry if I need to clear my cache.

There are about 20 cache cleaners for Chrome I found, but this one seemed lightweight and zero effort. In an update, Cache Killer can now stay "always on".

*Note: I do not know the plugin author in any way.  I just found it useful.*

Comment: Yep, the Chrome Dev Tools option doesn't seem to work for me. But cache killer works like a charm. The reload time is significantly slower, like 4-5x, but the actual serving up of the new content is obviously much quicker.

Comment: Clear Cache and Disable Cache are working only when working on localhost, on my mac. For online content I m refreshing and refreshing hoping to see any changes. This extension is a lifesaver.

Comment: I have found that using Disable Cache causes issues with local storage,  specifically angular-storage with Auth0.  Cache Killer works perfectly and does not cause issues with local storage.

Comment: Didn't work well for me on Chrome. This caused side effects such as loading images twice I found and it was hard to locate the problem to this extension.

Comment: This incredible extension! It was a pain to work with angular js ngRoute. +1

Comment: +1.  Cache Killer has made my life better more than most things. However, on OSX (mac) it does not refresh the favicon appearing in the tab, unless CMD-R is use. I wonder why.

Comment: I think the plugin is removed from web store. How can I manually install it and any ideas why it was removed?

Comment: Since the chrome store URL for CacheKiller is down, use this URL to download the CRX file, then drag the file into your chrome extension window to install it: https://www.crx4chrome.com/extensions/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap/

Comment: Removed from Chrome Extensions Store because of malware :( Alternatives?

Comment: The wonders of leddit https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/6d4tms/chrome_extension_cache_killer_gone/dp4uzz6/ just no clue about license etc so dunno if this sticks.

Comment: Ended up writing my own, works the same but can toggle per tab. MIT License and no malware, I promise ! https://github.com/themichaelyang/cache-clearer

Comment: @Michael thanks for lettings us know regarding your extension.

Answer (score 206):

[image: Picture of reload menu]

1. Pull up the Chrome developer console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and then (with the console open):
2. Right click (or hold left click) on the reload button at the top of the browser and select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload."

This will go beyond "Hard Reload" to empty the cache entirely, ensuring that anything downloaded via javascript or etc. will also avoid using the cache. You don't have to mess with settings or anything, it's a quick 1-shot solution.

Comment: well it definitely doesn't work on mac though, I've clicked that reload button with various key-combinations ;)

Comment: @ManirajSS: It will reload everything and avoid using the cache, but it will not re-download things downloaded by javascript after page load. I'm not sure why anyone would ever use it, but I guess you could come up with a few corner cases where it would be useful.

Comment: Nor will it clear cache for iframes inside of the page.

Comment: Not sure how long this has been true, but as of Chrome 41, click and hold on the reload button works on OS X, provided you have the developer tools window open.

Answer (score 50):

There are two more options to **disable page caching in Chrome for good**:

**1. Deactivate Chrome Cache in the Registry**

Open Registry (Start -> Command -> Regedit)

Search for: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`

Change the part after ...chrom.exe" to this value:  `–disable-application-cache –media-cache-size=1 –disk-cache-size=1 — "%1"`

Example: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -disable-application-cache –media-cache-size=1 –disk-cache-size=1 — "%1"`

IMPORTANT:

- there is a space and a hyphen after ...chrome.exe"
- leave the path to chrome.exe as it is
- If you copy the line, be sure to check, if the quotes are actual quotes.

**2. Deactivate Chrome cache by changing the shortcut properties**

Right-click on the Chrome icon and select "Properties" in the context menu.
Add following value to the path:  `–disk-cache-size=1`

Example:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" –disk-cache-size=1`

IMPORTANT:

- there is a space and a hyphen after ...chrome.exe"
- leave the path to chrome.exe as it is

Comment: Good answer. Though for most people disabling the cache is just a temporary thing during development. Disabling it permanently will slow down a normal browsing experience significantly and is kind of bad internet citizenship as it puts unnecessary load on the web servers your visiting.

Comment: I don't agree with the bad internet citizenship thing, we're talking here about creating some shortcut for dev work. So this is definitely the best answer IMHO. Just a small thing. Every time I copy this on Windows from this SO page into some Chrome shortcut, some of the chars don't come out right. These are the right ones: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --disable-application-cache --media-cache-size=1 --disk-cache-size=1` Also, what is the char right before  `"%1"` ? That I don't know.

Comment: i'm looking for chrome cli arguments to launch it without cache (for CI purposes). these don't seem to do anything. if i load a page, then reload it using F5 (NOT ctrl+F5), the cache is still used. did anything change in these regards on chromium in the last 3 years?

Comment: just found that --media-cache-size has been removed 2 years ago: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1661077

Answer (score 35):

If you do not wish to edit Chrome's settings you may use incognito mode for the same results.

Answer (score 23):

1. <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Chrome DevTools
2. <kbd>F1</kbd> to open DevTools Settings
3. Check *Disable cache (while DevTools is open)* as shown below:

This is currently on the *Preferences* tab which is the default. You may need to scroll down. This checkbox has been moved at least a couple times since this question was asked. Last I checked, it was in the middle column at the bottom. If you have it open on a thinner screen and there are 2 columns under Preferences, it may be near the top right. Feel free to update this post if it changes or comment and I'll update the post.

[image]

Comment: This does same thing as checking "Disable cache" directly at F12 Chrome Devtools and it will reset when you restart Chrome.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the disable cache option (which you get to via a button in the lower right corner of the developer tools window -- Tools | Developer Tools, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>), on the network pane of the developer tools you can now right click and choose "Clear Cache" from the popup menu.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of hitting "F5"
Just hit:

> "Ctrl + F5"

Comment: It also works in Firefox (not because it's relevant for this question, but somebody might find it useful)

Answer (score 17):

In the Canary Channel (and maybe the dev and stable channel will follow along) this is to be found as the second option overall on the left hand-side under the "General" section.

[image: Disable Cache in Chrome Canary Channel]

In addition to that, there is always the option to switch into Incognito Mode via Ctrl + Shift + N. Even though that unfortunately also ends your session.

Comment: In my experience this only works while dev tools are opened. I was puzzled why the cache was still holding onto pages until I realized I had closed the dev tools. It is odd the setting doesn't override everything.

Comment: Incognito mode does cache some images and files unfortunately.

Answer (score 15):

To be clear, the disable cache checkbox in Chrome (v17 here, but since v15 I believe) is not in the main settings UI. It is in the developer tools settings UI.

1. From the browser window's wrench icon menu (prefs menu) choose Tools → Developer Tools
2. In the developer tools UI that appears, click the gear icon at bottom right.
3. Check the 'Disable cache' checkbox in the Network section.

Answer (score 14):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh was nice but didn't get everything I needed.
still some things wouldn't refresh, such as data stored in js and css.
found a solution: a [toolbar of google for chrome web developers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm#). After you install the toolbar select options and "reset page".

Comment: +1. Still not perfect though: For developing on a local computer the cache is completely unneccessary and will introduce problems, so I would still be interested in a disable-feature like firebug has.

Answer (score 14):

Disable cache in chrome only works when you have dev tools open

Comment: maybe it is a bug or maybe it is only intended for developers - that said I would have thought non-developers would like to use the disable cache option too ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 14):

Until the bug is fixed you could use [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn/related) Chrome plugin and you can also set a keyboard shortcut for it.

After installing it, right click and go to options:

[image]

Check `Automatically reload active tab after clearing data`:

[image]

Select `Everything` for Time Period:

[image]

And then you can go to Menu => Tools => Extensions:

[image]

Click on keyboard shortcuts at the bottom:

[image]

And set your keyboard shortcut, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Actually if you don't mind using the bandwidth it is more secure for multiple reasons to disable caching and advised by many security sites.

Chromium shouldn't be arrogant enough to make decisions and enforce settings on users.

You can disable the cache on UNIX with --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null.

As this is unexpected crashes may happen but if they do then that will clearly point to a more severe bug which should be fixed in any case.

Answer (score 8):

This might help someone.

I have rigged my Nginx for crazy caching. Thus, disabling cache in network tools and explicitly clearing cache don't work.

A very simple yet boring workaround is, I just open a new Incognito Tab. Surprisingly it works, all the time!

A hard refresh in incognito mode does the trick anytime I wish to reload in the same mode.

Answer (score 8):

When this question was asked, Chrome didn't support the Disable Cache feature. But now, you can find the "Disable Cache" feature in Network Tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

### Network Tab with Cache Disabled

[image: Screenshot - Disable Cache Feature in Chrome Dev Tools]

You can see that all the resources (I have filtered JS resources) have been fetched from network and not loaded from disk/memory cache.

### Disable Cache not selected

[image]

You can see that when I refreshed the page but didn't select the "Disable Cache" feature, almost all the resources were loaded from Cache.

This works fine for local web development but there are certain limitations that I'd like to highlight. You can stop reading here if the solution discussed so far meets your use case.

### Limitations

1. You have to keep the DevTools Open and Disable Cache Selected
2. When you disable the cache, it is disabled for all the resources in that tab. It makes things slow and is inefficient if you want to disable cache for only 1-2 resources

### Using [Requestly Chrome Extension](https://requestly.io) to disable Cache for particular resources (JS/CSS/Images, etc)

Recently, I stumbled upon https://dev.to/requestlyio/disable-caching-of-particular-js-css-file-2k82 which helped me understand how you can disable cache for specific resources.

The trick here is to add a query parameter to your resource with random value every time the request is made. Using Requestly Query Param Rule, you can add a param like this

```
URL Contains mywebsite.com/myresource.js
Add param cb rq_rand(4)
```

> rq_rand(4) is replaced by 4 digits random number when a request is made.

### Requestly Query Parameter Rule to add random parameter

[image]

### After adding the rule, JS/CSS files are not cached

[image: Requestly Rule applied and added a random parameter to disable cache]

Here you can see that "Disable Cache" is not selected and still the resources are not loaded from Cache because of a random parameter (cb - Read it as Cache buster) in the URL.

1. The good thing is you don't need to keep your dev tools open for having this behavior
2. You can keep this permanently ON and your browsing experience won't be affected too.

### How to get the Rule

Here is the link using which you can browse & download the rule if you have Requestly installed - https://app.requestly.io/rules/#sharedList/1600501411585-disable-cache-stackoverflow

Disclaimer: I built Requestly but I think this could be helpful to a lot of web developers and hence sharing here.

Answer (score 6):

How about a bookmarklet which changes the page name to prevent the page from cacheing. In Chrome you would create a new bookmark and then paste the code into the URL. Click the bookmark and the page will reload with timestamp to thwart the cache.

```
javascript:(function(){var idx = location.href.indexOf('?');var d = new Date();var str = location.href.substr(0,idx) + '?version=' + d.getTime();location.href=str; void 0;})();
```

Answer (score 6):

I just got caught out but not necessarily due to Chrome.

I am using jQuery to make AJAX requests. I had the cache attribute set to true in the request:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        ....
```

Setting this to **false** fixed my problem but this is not ideal.

I have no idea where this data is saved but I do know that chrome never hit the server for a request.

Answer (score 5):

There is a better and quicker way now (Chrome version 59.x.x.):

Right-click onto the reload-icon (left of the url-field) and you get a drop-down menu, select the third option: 'empty Cache and Hard reload'.

This option is only available when the developer tools are open.
(Notice the difference to option 2: 'Hard reload' -cmd-shift-R). No cache emptying here!

Answer (score 3):

There is a chrome extension available in the chrome web store named [**Clear Cache**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn).

I use it every day and its a very useful tool I think. You can use it as a reload button and can clear the cache and if you like also cookies, locale storage, form data etc. Also you can define on which domain this happens. So can clear all this shit with only the reload button which you anyway have to press - on your chosen domains.

Very very nice!

You also can define a Keyboard Shortcut for this in the options!

Also another way is to start your chrome window in incognito-mode.
Here the cache also should be completely disabled.

Comment: Can't find the option to define on which domain it does it. Doesn't look very good. How about https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap/ ..?

Comment: go to clearcache icon in the browser, rightclick, options and then under cookies. There is a little settings icon.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **ServiceWorkers** (e.g.: for Progressive web apps), you'll likely need to check "Update on reload" under Application > Service Workers in dev tools too.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One more option for disabling the cache is provided by my 3rd Chrome extension [Page Size Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-size-inspector/oepnndnpjiahgkljgbohnnccmokgcoln) that disables the cache exactly the same way as Devtools does.

In addition, the extension quickly reports page size, cache usage, network requests and load time of a web page in a convenient way. Plus its open source at [Github](https://github.com/tomimick/chrome-ext-page-size).

[image: Screenshot - Page Size Inspector]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are using, but if you are using ASP.Net you can do the following which works like a charm:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")?time=@DateTime.Now" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Basically it will automatically append the Date and Time to the end of the file each time it is ran, meaning since the file name is technically different, you will never have to worry about it getting cached again.

Comment: absolutely. I used this, and conditional compilation, so it does not appear in test and release builds.

Comment: Even better way is to use css files modification time as a variable value. That solution can be used in production environment also. It just works :) Not sure how it's done in ASP but in PHP something like this <link href="style.css?time=<?php echo fileminfo('style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I tried :

- Control Shift R,
- Disable cache in F12
- Control F5.

Then I discovered that using **a .appcache manifest for a non https site is deprecated**. 
I removed my site.appcache file and its reference in the html tag and now I'm seeing the latest version of each page!

Answer (score 1):

Since version 50 (if I remember correctly), the "Disable cache" option was removed from the Devtool Settings. Go to the "Network" tab and there's the "Disable cache" option.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "annoying" cache in general layes in the framework :). Let's see details.
Most of frameworks uses in .htaccess (os equivalnent) derective redirecting all requests to frameworks "index",

BUT it the same time EXCLUDE files and directories requested by application directly.

(f.e. as for .htaccess typical directives are:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

)

Thus ALL .js, .css files as graphics ones are not handled by frameworks "index".

And those files are generally most often changed during development.

**That's why the cache control derective should not be placed in frameworks "index".**

**It should be palced in .htaccess.**

F.e. for development process use:

```
  Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
  Header set Pragma "no-cache"
```

(Or for consecutive working versions, use "Etag" directive - check more in HTTP reference. Notice, that ETag is not intended for development.

In .htaccess there is no direct way to generate random number (or fast changing sequence like date UTC) to use in ETag, because - as I mentioned before - this is not what this is provided for).

Hope it helps and saves time.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a Chrome extension that **disables browser cache for specific websites**.

Take a look – it's called [Cache Disabler](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension). Here's how it appears in action:

[image: Screenshot of “Cache Disabler” Chrome extension]

With it, you can **see your changes immediately** without relying on the hit-and-miss Ctrl+refresh.

There's no shortage of Chrome extensions that disable cache. However, what sets [Cache Disabler](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension) apart is its ability to **persist and sync your settings after a browser restart**. As far as I know, no other extension offers that, which is always appreciated when developing websites.

[It's open-source](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension), any feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hey if your site is using PHP then place following little PHP snippet at the beginning of your html page :

```
   //dev versioning - stop caching
   $rand = rand(1, 99999999);
```

Now everywhere you load resources like CSS- or JS- files in a script or link element you append your generated random value to the request URL after appending '?' to the URI via PHP:

```
    echo $rand;
```

Thats it! There will be no browser that caches you site anymore - regardless which kind.

Of course remove your code before publishing or simply set $rand to an empty string to allow caching again.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the other options described above but I find that the best is to add the following parameter to the startup of chrome.exe.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disk-cache-size=1
-media-cache=1

I find not disabling media cache is a good idea but it is here for completeness sake.

In actuality I want an option to completely disable the cache, to use the memory for IO instead of my disk (which would make load time 10x faster too!) but I don't think chrome or any browser for that matter has that option yet.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I disable the cache temporarily or refresh the page in some way that I could see the changes?

**It's unclear which "cache" you're referring to.** There are several different methods a browser can cache content persistently. [Web Storage](http://devdocs.io/dom-web-storage/) being one of them, [`Cache-Control`](http://devdocs.io/http/headers/cache-control) being another.

Some browsers also have a [`Cache`](http://devdocs.io/dom/cache), used in conjunction with [Service Workers](http://devdocs.io/dom-service-workers/), to create Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) providing offline support.

**To clear the cache for a PWA**

```
self.caches.keys().then(keys => { keys.forEach(key => console.log(key)) })
```

to list the names of the cache keys, then run:

```
self.caches.delete('my-site-cache')
```

to delete a cache key by name (i.e., `my-site-cache`). Then refresh the page.

If you see any worker-related errors in the console after refreshing, you may also need to unregister the registered workers:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
  .then(registrations => {
    registrations.forEach(registration => {
      registration.unregister()
    }) 
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's Cache killer is by far the best option. Since the store URL to install cache killer is down, you can download the CRX file here:

https://www.crx4chrome.com/extensions/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap/

once the extension file is downloaded, open Chrome -> more tools -> extensions, then drag the CRX file from the File Explorer or your Desktop (depending the location where you downloaded the file) into the chrome window to install the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a situation that the browser load the cache data from disk even I checked it disabled cache (I was using Chrome). All my CSS and JS were loading from server but not the web page. This was happening on both my local and Production.

To fixed it, I need to put an extra param in my URL to force the browser to get the web page from server, even the controller did not need it.

I was using ASP.Net, so here is my example :

```
//Controller function
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
//Link
@Html.Action("Index", "Home", new { ts = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()})
```

The result is, it will generate a link like: 
http://www.myweb.com/Home/Index?ts=636558555408282209

This is my situation and solution. Hopefully it could help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I use (in windows), ctrl + shift + delete and when the chrome dialog comes up, press enter key. This can be configured with what needs to be cleared each time you execute this sequence. No need to have dev. tools open in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging in VS Code using Chromium, I add a `runtimeArgs` of `--aggresive-cache-discard` to my `launch.json` file. That eliminates all caching. Code changes immediately appear when I refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Add this string of code to your  and it should do the trick.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">
```